# Swashbuckle Swagger UI FormData Type undefined

Tags: swagger-ui, swashbuckle

[image]

I'm using Swashbuckle 5.1.5 for my rest API for upload images, but form data parameters Data Type is coming up as undefined. How do you set the Data Type?

```
operation.parameters.Add(new Parameter
{
   name = "file",
   required = true,
   type = "file",
   @in = "formData"
}
```

Comment: It looks like screenshot is doesn't match to code. Description isn't set in code but is displayed on screenshot

Answer (score 0):

This should be working fine. I am using the latest swashbuckle version. Can you try with the latest version